# If yield is a closure inside a layout, then how does layouts are rendered within?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, closures

In Rails, if yield is a closure inside a layout, then how does controller can dictate which layout to render?

`layout :render => "myLayout"`

Comment: It should be render layout: "myLayout" in a controller action.

Answer (score 0):

The `layout` command in a controller can also accept a symbol, which links it to a method. Like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :admin_user
      "devise_admin"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

end
```

So, you can use this to switch out which layout you want to use from within the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a layout for an controller

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_layout

  protected

  def set_layout
    render :layout => 'Your-layout'
  end
end
```